# How to correctly configure htaccess in subdirectory Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, routes

I am currently following this guide to allow the running of our current legacy PHP application inside of Laravel with a view to migrating over totally over time.
https://tighten.co/blog/converting-a-legacy-app-to-laravel/

To this end I have managed to get Laravel to run the legacy application index.php file however I believe there may be some issue with the routing as the URL is not correct and the login page does not load.

Here is my current file structure, I have two .htaccess files one at the root of laravel and one in the root of the legacy folder.

[image: file structure of project1]

The laravel root htaccess file is rewriting the public folder so it should not show in the URL while working on dev.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The legacy applications .htaccess file handles all the routing for the views and files of the old system, see below.

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz

# HSTS Header - removed https only as AWS lb > server is http
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"

# core redirects
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /legacy

RewriteRule ^login/?$ /views/login/index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^app-redirect?$ /callback/apps/redirect_device.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^login/logout?$ /views/login/logout.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^register([/]*)$ /views/login/register.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^login/change-password([/]*)$ /views/login/change_password.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^authenticate/auth-check([/]*)$ /views/login/auth_check.php [QSA,L]
```

It also appears to be affecting the public URL rewrite when accessing the application as it adds public back into the URL like so:

**system.co.uk/public/login**

when it should be

**system.co.uk/login**

**Summary**:

So I have it successfully running the index.php file located in the legacy folder however it just stops there it doesn't appear to be taking any of the routes in the legacy .htaccess file like /login into the account.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? Experiencing a similar issue following the same guide

Comment: I sort of fixed it, however not in the way I hoped.
The root .htaccess file redirects everything to index.php and runs the laravel app fine however this also goes for any other routes coming to the application.

This is handled by the laravel routes however as its a catch all fallback for any legacy route, I have had to create my own routing controller due to the legacy routes being defined in the old htaccess file which is not processed as laravel takes over the routing from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

the htaccess file under the legacy folder shouldn't affect the root folder.
redirects can be cached by your browser, have you tried other browser or used incognito mode?

Comment: Thanks and yes, I have even tried breaking the htaccess file to check its picking up changes and its picking up the changes as soon as I make them and not caching from what I can see.